# How to find the cause of my Packet Loss?

Tags: networking, switch, packet-loss

I am using Internet from my University. All rooms and offices are connected with Ethernet cable through many switches. Many times I have packet loss, I think one switch or modem is problematic. How to identify the cause? 
(I know many info are missing but tell me what you need to know and I will update the question)

```
ping -t google.com
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=48
Request timed out.
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=77ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=70ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=77ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=99ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=87ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=98ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=108ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=98ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=83ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=70ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=101ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=101ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=96ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=98ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=101ms TTL=48
Request timed out.
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=96ms TTL=48
Request timed out.
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=99ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=122ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=98ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=96ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=98ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=94ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=96ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=88ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=95ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=122ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=88ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=100ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=99ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=94ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=95ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=101ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=88ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=94ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=78ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=94ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=100ms TTL=48
Request timed out.
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=95ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=99ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=94ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=96ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=101ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=96ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=95ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=74ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=90ms TTL=48
Reply from 216.58.211.46: bytes=32 time=87ms TTL=48

Ping statistics for 216.58.211.46:
    Packets: Sent = 128, Received = 123, Lost = 5 (3% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 70ms, Maximum = 131ms, Average = 94ms
```

Comment: Report the packet loss to the tech team at the university and let them handle it? It really is not something you can tackle yourself

Comment: I can have access to switches, tech team are my friends and they work voluntary for this building but not for whole university.

Comment: [edit] and provide the output from pathping or similar to pinpoint where the packet loss is occurring.

Comment: Can you say me the command?

Comment: @dpiralis [pathping](http://ss64.com/nt/pathping.html) - Trace route and provide network latency and packet loss for each router and link in the path. Combines the functionality of PING and TRACERT.

Comment: Ok I will update when traffic is high because now there are less than 1% packet loss.